# What are the Build controller and Build agent in TFS?

Tags: azure, tfs

I want to know the definition of the Build controller and Build Agent on TFS with an explanation; how they work, and what their uses are.

Answer (score 1):

**Build Controller (Source [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330987.aspx))**

> To use Team Foundation Build, your team must have at least one build
>   controller to perform lightweight tasks and distribute the
>   processor-intensive work of your build process to its pool of build
>   agents.

**Build Agent (Source [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399135.aspx))**

> To use Team Foundation Build, your team must have at least one build
>   agent to perform the processor-intensive work of your build process.

Those pages cover most of it in detail, but a TLDR Version is:

The controller orchestrates build agents. Agents run the build. If you want multiple builds to run at the same time, add more agents (on the same or different machines).

You don't normally need more than one controller, unless you have more than one Team Project Collection, or a real load of builds / agents. We happily run 24 agents and 1 controller on the same box.